# Does a NoSQL db limit future app functionality?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, nosql, rdbms

I am from an RDMS background and struggling to get my head around the idea of NoSQL DBs. I have read, read & read and I still cannot understand the advantage other than relationships can be stored as subcollections instead of related tables.

In a traditional db the structure needs to be designed in advance and then all operations are possible. This provides future flexibility.

Would it be fair to say that in a NoSQL environment the outputs need to be known in advance so the data can be stored according?

i.e. if a particular dashboard or report is not identified at the outset then in 6 months time it will be more difficult to add in a NoSQL environment as the data has previous data has not been stored to accomodate this new functionality?

Comment: From personal experience i can tell you that a nosql db is much more flexible than a SQL db. I would try to avoid using a SQL db for app data as I feel it's usually more naturally learning towards the unstructured.

Comment: What about ensuring data integrity? The word flexibility scares me.

Comment: Obviously by nature if you allow dynamic schema maintaining integrity is not as easy, Mongo does support db level validation though, it just has to be manually set up for each collection.

Comment: IT depends on your skills and nothing else. SQL sucks when you don’t know how to use it and NoSQL sucks just as hard when you don’t know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is fair to say

With nosql most work needs to be done upfront where work is identifying data access patterns.

It can be extremely difficult in the future to go in a retrofit new functionalities but not necessarily impossible

Comment: So when building a prototype MVP application NoSQL could be problematic choice as functionality is almost certain to evolve.

Comment: Yes. You should almost always start with postgres sql rdms when starting out

Comment: Exactly the insight I was after as this confirms what I had suspected was a fundamental difference between the two.